# Which bundle system should be used AMD, CommonJS, ES Module, IIFE, UMD and SystemJS

Tags: javascript

RollupJS module bundler provides a list of possible outputs

- AMD
- CommonJS
- ES Module
- IIFE
- UMD
- SystemJS

**Is there a rule of thumb which format should be chosen under a certain circumstance?**

```
amd – Asynchronous Module Definition, used with module loaders like RequireJS
cjs – CommonJS, suitable for Node and Browserify/Webpack
es – Keep the bundle as an ES module file
iife – A self-executing function, suitable for inclusion as a <script> tag. (If you want to create a bundle for your application, you probably want to use this, because it leads to smaller file sizes.)
umd – Universal Module Definition, works as amd, cjs and iife all in one
system – Native format of the SystemJS
```

Comment: _"IIFE"_ <- one of these things is not like the others

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Building modules and handling dependencies was cumbersome in the past. Newer solutions, in the form of libraries or ES2015 modules, have taken most of the pain away. **If you are looking at starting a new module or project, ES2015 is the right way to go**. It will always be supported and current support using transpilers and polyfills is excellent. On the other hand, **if you prefer to stick to plain ES5 code, the usual split between AMD for the client and CommonJS/Node for the server remains the usual choice**.

I recommend the lecture of this article, where you will find all the details, *pros* and *cons* for each module system :

https://auth0.com/blog/javascript-module-systems-showdown/

Comment: This is probably better as a comment. Link-only answers are of very low value

Comment: its an article but `umd` is missing from the article. thanks :)